# How can i check if the category has products or empty wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

hello guys i'm trying to know if a specific category with some custom attributes has a product or not but i don't know how to use this function to check if it has or no

```
 $isset_products_in_category = new WP_Query(
      array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'relation'=>'AND',
        'tax_query'           => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'product_cat',
            'field'           => 'term_id',
            'terms'           => '5',
            'operator'        => 'IN',
          ),
          array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
            'field'           => 'term_id',
            'operator'        => 'IN',
            'terms' => '2',
          ),
        ),
        'ignore_stickie_posts' => true,
        'fields' => 'ids',
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `'relation' => 'AND'` should be part of the `tax_query` array in `WP_Query()` (it defines the [relationship between the arrays in the `tax_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#:%7E:text=Important%20Note%3A%20tax_query%20takes%20an%20array%20of%20tax%20query%20arguments%20arrays%20(it%20takes%20an%20array%20of%20arrays).%0AThis%20construct%20allows%20you%20to%20query%20multiple%20taxonomies%20by%20using%20the%20relation%20parameter%20in%20the%20first%20(outer)%20array%20to%20describe%20the%20boolean%20relationship%20between%20the%20taxonomy%20arrays.)).
2. Your not doing anything with the result of the query. You could check the count:

Revised code example:

```
<?php 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
      'relation'=>'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'product_cat',
        'field'           => 'term_id',
        'terms'           => '5',
        'operator'        => 'IN',
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
        'field'           => 'term_id',
        'terms'           => '2',
        'operator'        => 'IN',
      ),
    ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids',
  )
);

// Do something with the result of the query
$isset_products_in_category = $wp_query->post_count > 0; 

var_dump($isset_products_in_category); // will output bool(true) or bool(false).
```